Why is the content of chapter notation pushed downward to the bottom of the page?
I have a chapter notations in class memoir
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,fullpage}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\sP}{\mathscr{P}}
\newcommand{\sB}{\mathscr{B}}
\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\trace}{tr}
\newcommand\smallO{
  \mathchoice
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \displaystyle
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \textstyle
    {{\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \scriptstyle
    {\scalebox{.6}{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}$}}%\scriptscriptstyle
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Notations}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
& \textbf{Sets and spaces} \\
$\bR_+$ & set of non-negative real numbers including $0$ \\
$\bN$ & set of natural numbers including $0$ \\
$\bN^*$ & set of natural numbers excluding $0$ \\
$\bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ & space of real matrices of size $d \times m$ \\
$\cB (\bR^d)$ & Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\bR^d$ \\
$\sP (\bR^d)$ & space of Borel probability measures on $\bR^d$  \\ 
$L^0 (\bR^d)$ & space of real-valued measurable functions on $\bR^d$ \\
$L^0_+ (\bR^d)$ & subset of $L^0 (\bR^d)$ that consists of non-negative functions \\
$L^0_b (\bR^d)$ & subset of $L^0 (\bR^d)$ that consists of bounded functions \\
$L^p (\bR^d)$ & Lebesgue space of real-valued $p$-integrable functions on $\bR^d$ \\
$\| \cdot \|_{L^p}$ & norm of $L^p (\bR^d)$ \\
$C_c (\bR^d)$ & space of real-valued continuous functions on $\bR^d$ with compact support \\
$C^\infty_c (\bR^d)$ & subspace $C_c (\bR^d)$ that consists of smooth functions \\
\\
& \textbf{Abbreviation} \\
w.r.t & with respect to \\
i.f.f & if and only if  \\
e.g. & for example \\
a.e. & almost everywhere \\
a.s. & almost surely \\
PDE & partial differential equation \\
SDE & stochastic differential equation \\
PoC & propagation of chaos \\
MV-SDE & McKean-Vlasov SDE \\
MP & martingale problem
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ l l }
& \textbf{Generic elements and operations} \\
$\rightharpoonup$ & weak convergence on $\sP (\bR^d)$ \\
$\overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}$ & weak-$*$ convergence on $\sP (\bR^d)$ \\
$\infty$ & plus infinity \\
$xy$ & matrix product of $x \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ and $y \in \bR^m \otimes \bR^n$ \\
$\langle x, y \rangle$ & Frobenius inner product of $x, y \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ \\
$|x|$ & Frobenius norm of $x \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ \\
$x \vee y$ & maximum between $x, y \in \bR$ \\
$x \wedge y$ & minimum between $x, y \in \bR$ \\
$x^+$ & maximum between $x \in \bR$ and $0$ \\
$x^*$ &  Hölder conjugate of $x \in [1, \infty]$, i.e., $1 = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^*}$ \\
$\operatorname{id}$ & identity function on $\bR^d$ \\
$I_d$ & identity matrix in $\bR^d \otimes \bR^d$ \\
$f_\sharp \mu$ & push-forward of measure $\mu$ through function $f$ \\
$\pi^i$ & projection of $\bR^d \times \bR^d$ onto $i$-th coordinate \\
$\diff x$ & Lebesgue measure on $\bR^d$ \\
$\nabla$ & gradient operator \\
$\nabla^2$ & Hessian matrix \\
$\Delta$ & Laplacian operator \\
$\Div$ & divergence operator \\
$\partial_{x_i}$ & derivative in spatial $x_i$ direction \\
$\partial_t$ & derivative in time \\
$x^\top$ & transpose of $x \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ \\
$\trace x$ & trace of $x \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^d$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}

Could you explain why the content is pushed downward to the bottom of the page?


Presumably because memoir uses flushbottom, it tries to maintain that that last line on a page lines up. You might want to use longtable here, it can break across pages whereas tabular cannot.

Don't use fullpage with memoir, they're incompatible.

If you only want a ragged bottom on certain pages, you can add \vspace*{\fill} where needed.

@JohnKormylo This answer gives exactly what I want in terms of margin.

By default memoir runs with \flushbottom, this has the effect of trying to keep the last line of pages on the same level. You can see it goes away if you add \raggedbottom to the preamble instead.
In your case it is a lot easier to just use the longtable package instead of manually breaking up the tabulars. As the page is properly filled out, there is no extra stretch at the first page.
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,fullpage}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\sP}{\mathscr{P}}
\newcommand{\sB}{\mathscr{B}}
\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\trace}{tr}
\newcommand\smallO{
  \mathchoice
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \displaystyle
    {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \textstyle
    {{\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \scriptstyle
    {\scalebox{.6}{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}$}}%\scriptscriptstyle
  }

\usepackage{longtable}
  
  
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Notations}

\begin{longtable}{ l l }
& \textbf{Sets and spaces} \\
$\bR_+$ & set of non-negative real numbers including $0$ \\
$\bN$ & set of natural numbers including $0$ \\
$\bN^*$ & set of natural numbers excluding $0$ \\
$\bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ & space of real matrices of size $d \times m$ \\
$\cB (\bR^d)$ & Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\bR^d$ \\
$\sP (\bR^d)$ & space of Borel probability measures on $\bR^d$  \\ 
$L^0 (\bR^d)$ & space of real-valued measurable functions on $\bR^d$ \\
$L^0_+ (\bR^d)$ & subset of $L^0 (\bR^d)$ that consists of non-negative functions \\
$L^0_b (\bR^d)$ & subset of $L^0 (\bR^d)$ that consists of bounded functions \\
$L^p (\bR^d)$ & Lebesgue space of real-valued $p$-integrable functions on $\bR^d$ \\
$\| \cdot \|_{L^p}$ & norm of $L^p (\bR^d)$ \\
$C_c (\bR^d)$ & space of real-valued continuous functions on $\bR^d$ with compact support \\
$C^\infty_c (\bR^d)$ & subspace $C_c (\bR^d)$ that consists of smooth functions \\
\\
& \textbf{Abbreviation} \\
w.r.t & with respect to \\
i.f.f & if and only if  \\
e.g. & for example \\
a.e. & almost everywhere \\
a.s. & almost surely \\
PDE & partial differential equation \\
SDE & stochastic differential equation \\
PoC & propagation of chaos \\
MV-SDE & McKean-Vlasov SDE \\
MP & martingale problem
  \\
& \textbf{Generic elements and operations} \\
$\rightharpoonup$ & weak convergence on $\sP (\bR^d)$ \\
$\overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}$ & weak-$*$ convergence on $\sP (\bR^d)$ \\
$\infty$ & plus infinity \\
$xy$ & matrix product of $x \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ and $y \in \bR^m \otimes \bR^n$ \\
$\langle x, y \rangle$ & Frobenius inner product of $x, y \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ \\
$|x|$ & Frobenius norm of $x \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ \\
$x \vee y$ & maximum between $x, y \in \bR$ \\
$x \wedge y$ & minimum between $x, y \in \bR$ \\
$x^+$ & maximum between $x \in \bR$ and $0$ \\
$x^*$ &  Hölder conjugate of $x \in [1, \infty]$, i.e., $1 = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^*}$ \\
$\operatorname{id}$ & identity function on $\bR^d$ \\
$I_d$ & identity matrix in $\bR^d \otimes \bR^d$ \\
$f_\sharp \mu$ & push-forward of measure $\mu$ through function $f$ \\
$\pi^i$ & projection of $\bR^d \times \bR^d$ onto $i$-th coordinate \\
$\diff x$ & Lebesgue measure on $\bR^d$ \\
$\nabla$ & gradient operator \\
$\nabla^2$ & Hessian matrix \\
$\Delta$ & Laplacian operator \\
$\Div$ & divergence operator \\
$\partial_{x_i}$ & derivative in spatial $x_i$ direction \\
$\partial_t$ & derivative in time \\
$x^\top$ & transpose of $x \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^m$ \\
$\trace x$ & trace of $x \in \bR^d \otimes \bR^d$ 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}

